# How to restore data from the snowflake after the create or replace is done done

Tags: sql, cloud, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have bymistake altered the table transient table in snowflake is there any way to retrieve the data I done 2 days back please suggest me . Any options I need to retrieve data .

Answer (score 1):

Transient table is by  its nature transient.

[Comparison of Table Types](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-temp-transient.html#comparison-of-table-types)

> Time Travel Retention Period (Days)  0 or 1
>
> Fail-safe Period (Days)              0

> Because transient tables do not have a Fail-safe period, they provide a good option for managing the cost of very large tables used to store transitory data; **however, the data in these tables cannot be recovered after the Time Travel retention period passes.**
>
> **For example, if a system failure occurs in which a transient table is dropped or lost, after 1 day, the data is not recoverable by you or Snowflake.** As such, we recommend using transient tables only for data that does not need to be protected against failures or data that can be reconstructed outside of Snowflake.

---

Options to check:

1. Clone of database from the past(maybe exists)/or for other reasons like cloned DEV databases
2. Reload from source data(either other table or external storage) - data may exist there
3. Data was consumed(1:1) by external tool(like reporting tool using Import Mode) or unloaded to external cloud storage.
4. Data was loaded using only `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)`(unlikely) , the queries could be found in [QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html).